# Почему не настраивается компиляция в нужную папку в liveSassCompile?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

Пользуюсь VSCode плагином **"Live sass compile"**.
Необходимо настроить компиляцию SASS в прошлую папку, делаю это следующим образом:

1. В VSCode открываю поиск по настройкам **(ctr + <)**, ввожу название **liveSassCompile.settings.formats**
2. Нажимаю **Edit in settings.json**
3. Ввожу

   ```
   "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
       "format": "compressed",
       "extensionName": ".min.css",
       "savePath": "../~"
   }]
   ```

   Но ни минификация, ни компиляция в нужную папку, не работает, компиляция файлов происходит по стандартным настройкам. 
   В чем может быть проблема?

**Офф. документация**:
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте путь относительно файла Sass или SCSS:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
  // CSS по умолчанию.
  {
    "format": "expanded",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "~/../css"
  },
  // Компрессированный CSS
  {
    "format": "compressed",
    "extensionName": ".min.css",
    "savePath": "~/../css"
  }
],
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не вставляйте картинки кода, добавьте сам код в ответ и отформатируйте его

Answer (score 0):

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
    "format": "compressed",
    "extensionName": ".min.css",
    "savePath": "/src/css"
}]
```

Необходимо указывать от корня, т.к путь `../~` не подходит по регулярке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставил "savePath": null, по идее он должен хотя бы минификацию в ту же папку делать?